# Plotting two different Matplotlib graphs in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am a newbie to Python.
I've been dabbling in Matplotlib for quite a while.
Here's the problem I ran into. I need to plot two different graphs in a row.
I tried plt.subplots(1,2,1) or something like this, but this seems not to have worked.

I want to have two sets of graphs Pk=f(Dk), Pk=f(Subcooling) depicted at the end of the program. Whenever I want to build a graph using only one parameter, it works. That said, I can't bring it to plot a graph for each variable. How can I tweak the code to achieve this end?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math
import pyXSteam.XSteam
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
sns.set_style("ticks",{'grid.linestyle': '--'})
sns.color_palette("Spectral", as_cmap=True)

steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) # m/kg/sec/°C/bar/W
A = float(input('Define the heat exchange area, sq.m: ')) #3000 m2
d_in = float(input('Define the inner diameter of a single HE tube, mm: ')) #20mm
CF = float(input('Define the cleanliness factor of the HE (0.8,0.85,0.9 etc): ')) #0.85
Gw=float(input('Define the CW flow, t/hr: ')) #13000 t/hr
z=float(input('Define the number of passes: ')) #1
rho=float(input('Define the density of the liquid, kg/m3: ')) #1000 kg/m3
N=float(input('Define the number of tubes in the HE: ')) #5096
def w():
    return ((Gw*1000/3600)*z*4*1000000)/(rho*math.pi*((d_in)**2)*N) #2.26 m/s - water velocity inside the tubes
Tcwin=float(input('Define some initial value of Tcwin:')) #20
#Tcwin=20 #assume some initial value for Tcwin
Dk=float(input('Define the max steam load, t/hr: ')) #274.18
def Cp():
    return steamTable.CpL_t(Tcwin)
def Ts():
    return np.vectorize(Tsat_theor)
def Psat_theor():
    return 100*steamTable.psat_t(Tsat_theor)
def dk():
    return Dk*1000/(A*3.600)
def K():
    return CF * 4070 * ((1.1 * w() / (d_in ** 0.25)) ** (0.12 * CF * (1 + 0.15 * Tcwin))) * (1 - (((35 - Tcwin) ** 2) * (0.52 - 0.0072 * dk) * (CF ** 0.5)) / 1000)
def Tcwout_theor():
    return Tcwin+(Dk*2225/(Gw*Cp()))
def Subcooling_theor():
    return (Tcwout_theor - Tcwin) / ((math.e ** (K * A / (Cp() * (Gw * 1000 / 3600) * 1000)))-1)
def TR_theor():
    return (Tcwout_theor - Tcwin)
def Tsat_theor():
    return (Tcwout_theor + Subcooling_theor)
def LMTD_theor():
    return TR_theor/math.log((Tsat_theor()-Tcwin)/(Tsat_theor()-Tcwout_theor()))
X = np.arange(Dk*0.1,Dk*1.1,Dk*0.1)
for Tcwin in np.arange(17,31,2):
    Y = []
    for Dk in X:
        dk = (Dk * 1000 / (A * 3.600)) #calculate the relative steam load
        K = CF * 4070 * ((1.1 * w() / (d_in ** 0.25)) ** (0.12 * CF * (1 + 0.15 * Tcwin))) * (1 - (((35 - Tcwin) ** 2) * (0.52 - 0.0072 * dk) * (CF ** 0.5)) / 1000)
        n = (K * A) / (Cp() * Gw * 1000)
        Tcwout_theor = Tcwin + (Dk * 2225 / (Cp() * Gw))
        Subcooling_theor = (Tcwout_theor - Tcwin) / ((math.e ** (K * A / (Cp() * (Gw * 1000 / 3600) * 1000)))-1)
        TR_theor = (Tcwout_theor - Tcwin)
        Tsat_theor = (Tcwout_theor + Subcooling_theor)
        Y.append(Psat_theor())
    plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--", c='gray')
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    plt.pause(0.25)
plt.xlabel(r'$D_{k}$' + ',т/ч', loc='right')
plt.ylabel(r'$P_{k}$' + ',кПа', rotation=0, loc='top')
plt.legend([r'$t_{1в}$' + '=17 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=19 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=21 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=23 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=25 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=27 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С',
            r'$t_{1в}$' + '=29 \N{DEGREE SIGN}С'])
plt.title(r'$P_{k}$' + '=f(' + '$D_{k}$' + ')')
sns.despine()
plt.subplots_adjust()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not reproducible without the variables.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney modified the code a bit